# django no reverse match error but i have optional view parameters

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have the following link that is getting a "no reverse match" error:

```
<a href="{% url 'journals:entry' action='add'  day_number=journal.day_number  %}" >
```

My url looks like this:

```
url(r'^day/(?P<day_number>\d+)/(?P<action>add|edit|delete)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.entry, name='entry'),
```

My view looks like this:

```
def entry(request, day_number=0, pk=None, action='add'):
```

I don't have a pk but I thought I don't need one since this param is optional.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `pk` argument.

```
<a href="{% url 'journals:entry' action='add'  day_number=journal.day_number pk=... %}" >
```

If you want to make `pk` optional, modify the pattern as follow:

```
url(r'^day/(?P<day_number>\d+)/(?P<action>add|edit|delete)/(?P<pk>\d+)?/$',
    views.entry, name='entry'),
```

Comment: but it is an optional parameter?

Comment: @Atma, It is not an optional parameter.

Comment: how can I make it optional?

Comment: @Atma, Modify the pattern: `....(?P<pk>\d+)?` (by appending `?` after the part that you want to make optional)

Comment: i thought if you set a parameter with a default it becomes optional? http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html

Comment: @Atma, That just makes view function parameter optional, but not url parameter.